# Using powershell, how can i re-run a release which has failed in azure-devops using an api?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

what can i put in which can help me re run a failed release in azure devops?

```
$timer = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 120
while ($sw.elapsed -lt $timer) {  
        $ReleaseStatus  = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/company/project/_apis/release/releases/$RId/environments/$EId/?`api-version=6.0" -Method GET -Headers $Header -Verbose
        start-sleep -seconds 10
        
        if ($ReleaseStatus.Status -eq 'Succeeded') {
            write-host "Release Succeeded"
            return
            }
        if ($ReleaseStatus.status -eq 'Rejected' -or 'active') {
                Invoke-RestMethod "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/company/project/_apis/release/releases?api-version=6.0" -Method POST -Headers $Header -Body $Body -Verbose
                write-host "Error occured, Re-running Release"
                return
            }
            
                    
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to request [this endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline)

Comment: i had to ping this endpoint Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/company/project/_apis/release/releases/$RId/environments/$EId/?`api-version=6.0" -Method GET -Headers $Header -Verbose - in the end which allowed me to rerun the release instead of creating and running a new one

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, feel free to post it below! :) [Self-answers are perfectly fine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: thanks @MathiasR.Jessen for your help and yeah i will do :)

Answer (score 1):

i had to ping this endpoint in the end.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "vsrm.dev.azure.com/company/project/_apis/release/releases/$RId/…?`api-version=6.0" -Method GET -Headers $Header -Verbose
```

This allowed me to rerun the release instead of creating and running a new one in my script.